# Oracle APEX cascading text fields with autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oracle11g, oracle-apex

At this moment I’m working on the Oracle APEX page which represents an input form (it is submitted by executing the JavaScript function, not by the page submit itself), and among other items there are three items which are displayed as text fields with autocomplete and should conform the following logic: the first one is **P100_ROOT**, the second one is **P100_BRANCH** and depends on the **P100_ROOT**, and the third one is **P100_LEAF** which depends on the both **P100_ROOT** and **P100_BRANCH**. Also, I need to make these items work this way:

- when all the items are null, **P100_BRANCH** and **P100_LEAF** are disabled;
- when **P100_ROOT** is not null and the others are null, then **P100_LEAF** is
  disabled;
- when **P100_ROOT** and **P100_BRANCH** are not null, then they are
  disabled and **P100_LEAF** is not.

To make the items follow this logic I’ve customized the settings of the fields as follows:

- “Lazy Loading” is set to “Yes” for **P100_BRANCH** and **P100_LEAF** and to “No” for **P100_ROOT** respectively;
- ”Cascading LOV Parent Item(s)” is set to “P100_ROOT” for **P100_BRANCH** and to “P100_ROOT,P100_BRANCH” for **P100_LEAF** respectively;
- ”Page Items to Submit” is set for the items **P100_BRANCH** and **P100_LEAF** to themselves;
- “Optimize Refresh” is set to “No” for all the items.

Also I wrote the JavaScript function *toggleCascadeItems* which accepts the “number” corresponding to the item ID (you can see it in this post below) and linked it to every item’s event “onBlur”.
However I’ve found out the difficulties with performing this task. Firstly, the events “onBlur” and “onChange” are triggered for text fields with autocomplete when user just picks any value from the pop-up list but not when it is really written in the field. Secondly, there is possibly one more event which triggers even after the item’s refresh (I mean the event “apexrefresh”), and because of that the items **P100_ROOT**, **P100_BRANCH** and **P100_LEAF** are not working properly: I mean that all the logic is executed, but then something happens with makes some items to get rid of the “disabled” attribute, and it’s not because of *toggleCascadeItems*.

To solve my problem I’ve tried the such things as:

- rewriting the JavaScript function *toggleCascadeItems* (I know, its code is redundant, but it’s all for the workaround of triggering the “apexrefresh” event) and linking it not only to “onBlur”/”onChange”, but also to “apexrefresh” event (see the code below for more information);
- getting rid of “Page Items to Submit” and saving the values of the above mentioned items in session with the help of PL/SQL procedure APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE;
- changing **P100_BRANCH** and **P100_LEAF** from text fields with autocomplete to select lists.

And none of them helped me to prevent the “disabled” attribute to disappear. I tried to find some information relating to my problem, but I haven’t got any result.

Here is the JavaScript function *toggleCascadeItems*:

```
function toggleCascadeItems(nMode){
  var page = 'P' + $v('pFlowStepId') + '_';
  if (nMode == 0) //p100_root
  {
      if ($("#" + page + "ROOT").val() == ''){
        $("#" + page + "ROOT").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#" + page + "BRANCH").attr('disabled','true');
        $("#" + page + "LEAF").attr('disabled','true');
      } else {
        if ($("#" + page + "BRANCH").val() == ''){
          $("#" + page + "ROOT").removeAttr('disabled');
          $("#" + page + "BRANCH").removeAttr('disabled');
          $("#" + page + "LEAF").attr('disabled','true');
        } else {
          $("#" + page + "ROOT").attr('disabled','true');
          if ($("#" + page + "LEAF").val() == ''){
            $("#" + page + "BRANCH").removeAttr('disabled');
            $("#" + page + "LEAF").removeAttr('disabled');
          } else {
            $("#" + page + "BRANCH").attr('disabled','true');
          }
        }
      }
  }
  else if (nMode == 1) //p100_branch
  {
      if ($("#" + page + "BRANCH").val() == ''){
        $("#" + page + "ROOT").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#" + page + "LEAF").attr('disabled','true');
        if ($("#" + page + "ROOT").val() == ''){
          $("#" + page + "BRANCH").attr('disabled','true');
        } else {
          $("#" + page + "BRANCH").removeAttr('disabled');
        }
      } else {
        $("#" + page + "ROOT").attr('disabled','true');
        $("#" + page + "LEAF").removeAttr('disabled');
        if ($("#" + page + "LEAF").val() == ''){
          $("#" + page + "BRANCH").removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
          $("#" + page + "BRANCH").attr('disabled','true');
        }
      }
  }
  else if (nMode == 2) //p100_leaf
  {
      if ($("#" + page + "LEAF").val() == ''){
        if ($("#" + page + "ROOT").val() == ''){
          $("#" + page + "ROOT").removeAttr('disabled');
          $("#" + page + "BRANCH").attr('disabled','true');
        } else {
          $("#" + page + "BRANCH").removeAttr('disabled');
          if ($("#" + page + "BRANCH").val() == ''){
            $("#" + page + "ROOT").removeAttr('disabled');
          } else {
            $("#" + page + "ROOT").attr('disabled','true');
          }
        }
      } else {
        $("#" + page + "ROOT").attr('disabled','true');
        $("#" + page + "BRANCH").attr('disabled','true');
      }
  }
  //console.log(nMode);
  //alert(nMode);
}
```

And this is some code from “Executed when Page Loads”:

```
  $("#P100_ROOT,#P100_BRANCH,#P100_LEAF").each(function(){
   $(this).bind('apexafterrefresh',function(event){
     var sID = $(this).attr('id');
     var nMode = ((sID == "P100_ROOT") ? 0 : (sID == "P100_BRANCH") ? 1 : (sID == "P100_LEAF") ? 2 : -1);
     toggleCascadeItems(nMode);
     //console.log('refresh ' + sID);
   });
   $(this).on('blur',function(event){
     var sID = $(this).attr('id');
     var nMode = ((sID == "P100_ROOT") ? 0 : (sID == "P100_BRANCH") ? 1 : (sID == "P100_LEAF") ? 2 : -1);
     toggleCascadeItems(nMode);
     //console.log('change ' + sID);
   });
  });
```

p.s. I use Oracle APEX 4.2.6.00.03, and also I have two necessary conditions: **P100_ROOT** should stay a text field with autocomplete (**P100_BRANCH** and **P100_LEAF** may be select lists), and the form should be still submitted by executing the JavaScript function.

Comment: You are using a very old version of APEX. Unfortunately, the solution to this type of problem will be very dependent on the version of APEX you're using. I could provide a solution based on APEX 19.2, but it wouldn't help you because the APEX items and JS APIs were very different then. I recommend you upgrade APEX to get more help online.

Comment: @DanMcGhan, thank you for this recommendation, but, unfortunately, I have no opportunity for upgrading Apex (I'm not the one who decides which version to use).